# How can I get all my installed vscode Extensions via something like a fetch in Javascript

Tags: visual-studio-code, next.js, fetch-api, vscode-extensions

I know how to get all local extensions installed via the terminal and just one line but that's not ideal for what I need them. I made a personal hobby website with NextJS and I have a site displaying all my extensions, currently I just have the output of the terminal plugged into a js file but that, as you can imagine, isn't really what I wanna do as soon as I install a new extension or disable/uninstall one...

I could imagine that there would be a git repo you can "ask" because I synced my extensions with my github account. Sadly Google won't tell me how... and I didn't find a magical Repo which was private in my github either

I hope there is a magic URL that I can fetch from to get a list of all names of the extensions installed for my account

Comment: When extensions can be synced, I wonder what exactly is missing for you, https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/settings-sync

Comment: I have them synces but not with my javascript website which in the end is what I essentially want. And I cant include it for the vscode sync because I dont know where it is located in the source code nor how I would only get the names instead of all the extensions